# can I share a multiprocessing.Manager() instance across 3 processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to understand if I'm allowed to do the following in python:

- create a [manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Manager) instance in my program
- fork the existing process N times
- in my initial process, send data to the manager (to some shared variable)
- in my forked processes, read data from the manager (from the shared variable)

Based on my understanding, it should be the main use-case for managers.
However, I am trying this for more than 2 processes I'm getting pickle errors sometimes when trying to do this. With only 2 processes it always works
My question is thus : is this supposed to work or not?

I wonder if maybe the Manager system is not based on a file-descriptor/socket so it's only made to communicate 1-to-1, or at least by default

Comment: Assuming that you are not pickling the manager instance to send it to other processes (putting it on a queue, pipe), this should work. However, for use-cases like this, it might be worth looking into starting a manager on a defined server:port and communicating with that from the other two processes to pass data.

Comment: the main problem is who will control starting and closing this manager ?, if it should just stay alive all the time, it should be launched separately, but if one should control its lifetime then who will ?

Comment: @AhmedAEK since there is a main process that is different from the others this one should handle the lifetime of the manager. But it's unrelated to the issue of just communicating with it once it's created

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't and shouldn't share a manager instance. [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) says "A manager object controls a server process which manages shared objects. Other processes can access the shared objects by using proxies."

The `multiprocessing.Manager` provides a RPC(remote procedure call) feature, similar to Java RMI and MS COM. So you should distinguish a server process from client processes. You need to understand the APIs such as `start()`, `serve_forever()`, `connect()`, etc. You don't need to call the low level API `fork()`.

This is an example of a RPC server and client.

```
import sys
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class MathsClass:
    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mode = sys.argv[1]
    if mode == 'server':
        MyManager.register('Maths', MathsClass)
        manager = MyManager(address=('localhost', 3000), authkey=b'')
        manager.get_server().serve_forever()
    elif mode == 'client':
        MyManager.register('Maths', MathsClass)
        manager = MyManager(address=('localhost', 3000), authkey=b'')
        manager.connect()
        maths = manager.Maths()
        print(maths.add(4, 3))
```

You can run a server and client by specifying the 'server' and 'client' command line argument respectively. It uses a TCP socket but other channels can be used such as a unix socket or a WIN32 named pipe.

As a side note, I'll explain how an official sample works. I chose it because it's somewhat confusing in my opinion. The following is one of the official samples, edited for brevity.

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class MathsClass:
    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

MyManager.register('Maths', MathsClass)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with MyManager() as manager:
        maths = manager.Maths()
        print(maths.add(4, 3))
```

In the `with MyManager() as manager:` line, `manager.start()` is called via a context manager. This creates a server process as a child process. The server waits for a remote call request from a client. Now the main process as a remote call client calls the `maths.add()`, where the `maths` is a proxy object. The `maths.add(4, 3)` call will serialize the method name and arguments into a remote call request, and send the request to the server(the child process). The server will parse the request, execute the actual implementation of the `MathsClass.add()`, serialize the return value into a remote call response, and send the response to the client(the main process).

Comment: Thanks, I understand you answer but your example isn't the case I'm describing.
My example would be, how can other processes connect and exchange data with the manager? In my example in order to achieve this, I'm forking the process that has the manager instance, but I'm not sure it's correct to do so

Comment: I'll add an example of explicitly creating a server and a client.

Comment: @Ahmed AEK, what is misleading exactly? You mean I chose an example which does not explicitly create a server? If it is, what about the updated answer?

Comment: thanks for the update ! is it possible that in your example you show how i's possible to transfer an object between main and client ?

Comment: The objects are serialized and parsed with the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) by default. So make your objects picklable and just pass as arguments.

Comment: yes, but how do you make it work with higher-level system like proxy objects in that case ? ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects )
I can send an object instance into the manager but I don't really see a simple for the client to know what to ask to retrieve the object from the manager

Comment: @lezebulon this question partially gives insight about sharing proxies, [Is it possible for multiple python files to use one queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75028655/is-it-possible-for-multiple-python-files-to-use-one-queue/75032406#75032406)

Comment: @lezebulon, why are you trying to send a proxy object? A proxy object always resides on a RPC client. It is a wrapper on the object with actual implementation, residing on the server. What's your desired communication pattern?

Comment: @relent95 just communicating with a shared object with several processes
After further investigations I found something that is never working : https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/101320 so I'm starting to think it's really an issue wihth python itself

Comment: @lezebulon, did you open that issue? As I commented on that issue, it's not guaranteed that the multiprocessing API will work correctly with an ```os.fork()``` call. Try ```multiprocessing.Process()``` and pass proxy objects in the args argument. See the 2nd example at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).