# Shared Variables in Multiprocess in Different Files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use shared variables on multiprocess. But I'm not able to manage any modification to deal with my necessity.
I'm using Manager().dict() because I need to spawn multiple process.

I have 2 files:

teste2.py:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Manager().dict()
```

teste.py:

```
import teste2

print(teste2.test)
```

when I execute teste.py I got this error (In researchs I found that main block is not executed on import):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(teste2.test)
AttributeError: module 'teste2' has no attribute 'test'
```

if I modify teste2.py to:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager

test = Manager().dict()
```

I got this error:

```
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Any idea how to manage to deal with this? I do the Manager().dict() in a separated file because I use it in serveral other files.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/75028655/16310741

Comment: I couldn't see how this issue fits to the mine or Am I missing Something? Could you detail it a bit more to fit to my example?

Comment: Basically, you start the manager at a predefined address and authkey (see code for server.py in the accepted answer) and connect to it from another file to share the dictionary (see client.py).